# Terminal command for changing ibus keyboard layout?

Tags: command-line, keyboard-layout, ibus

Is it possible to use terminal commands to switch between keyboard layouts in `ibus`? I can't see any GUI way to do it in XFCE.

Comment: @DKBose The default keyboard layout app in XFCE didn't have any option for the keyboard layout I need (phonetic Tamil.) That's why I installed `ibus`. I have Lubuntu, but I've installed `xubuntu-desktop` and mostly use that. The only way I've found now is to log out of XFCE, into Lubuntu to switch layout, then back into XFCE.

Comment: I admit I do not know if it works in your case --- I have ibus installed but I am not sure I'm using it --- can you try `setxkbmap -query` when you have the correct layout, and `setxkbmap -layout XX -variant YYYYYY -option A:B,C:D` to switch? obviously substitute XX, YYY etc. with the output that `-query` gives to you.

Comment: @Rmano `setxkbmap -query` tells me that the layout is `gb`,  no matter if I have Tamil or US English active.

Comment: @Rmano please post your comment as an answer, it actually answers the question posed, which is shown in google not the underlying personal problem of the asker. I needed this to define a custom shortcut for Ctrl+2 to set an often needed language instead of always having to choose in the switching menu shown in the switch-shortcut (super+space for me)

Comment: @mxmlnkn, done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, `ibus` provides an system tray applet.

1. Run `ibus-setup`
2. On *General* tab, Check *Show icon on system tray*
3. On *General* tab, confirm you have shortcut
4. On *Advanced* tab,Uncheck *Use system keyboard layout*

[image: ibus applet]

Comment: Yes, works quite well, thank you. Just tried it on Lubuntu Xenial while logged into XFCE.

Answer (score 5):

It's more related to `xkb` than to `ibus` (but I am not sure I completely understand the intricacy of the keyboard handling, as you can see in [this post of mine](http://rlog.rgtti.com/2014/05/01/how-to-modify-a-keyboard-layout-in-linux/)) but you can detect the current configuration with

```
[romano:~] % setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     es,gb
variant:    standard_tlde,
options:    caps:none,compose:caps,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp
```

note it down, and then use

```
setxkbmap -layout es -variant standard_tlde -option caps:none,compose:caps,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp
```

that you can associate to a key. It should work in all Ubuntu flavors, at least X11-based (no idea about wayland).

Answer (score 4):

Use ibus command
to set m17n

```
ibus engine m17n:te:itrans
```

to set `us`

```
ibus engine xkb:us::eng
```

list engines

```
ibus list-engine
```

show available engines

```
ibus read-config
```

Comment: Unfortunately it resets to the GUI-selected one as soon as you switch terminal (even if you switch back).

Comment: Finally I can change layout using keyboard binding in i3. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

*checked answer is not the answer for the question title.*

### Easier way to use Ibus with command ↓

#### Get Engine Name

- type to terminal but **don't execute**: `ibus engine`
- change ibus to the engine you want to know the engine name
- execute the command. Output is the engine name

#### Change Ibus Engine

- Command: `ibus engine ENGINE_NAME`. (ex: `ibus engine xkb:us::eng`)
- `ENGINE_NAME` is the name that you got from above step.